# Access control for items served from CDN

Tags: cdn, access-control

I was looking at the network request/response made by photos.google.com. When I clicked on an album, as expected, the server just returned a list of photo IDs in the album and the cdn url to download the photos. Then my browser made another request(s) to Google CDN using the urls returned earlier and downloaded the photos.

The CDN url looked something like (intentionally modified to post here): 
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rpFgzMwheqshfkwelrklsjfkwejjlfjlsjfjsfjweojjsf

When I pasted the url in browser, it was able to download the photo even when I was not signed in.

So how does Google does access control at the CDN level? Does that mean I can access any photo of anyone if I know the random key at the end (I understand it's impossible to guess because it's a really really long random string)? How does Google generate this really long random url for each resource and maintain the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking about user profile pictures, yes they can access them. Google has an official API for this.